# Cannot generate exception: very simple C# Windows Form Application and app.config

Tags: c#, app-config

I am brand new to C# (VS 2010) and I'm trying to understand how to handle Exceptions.
Except, with the very simple program I've written, I can't generate one.

Here's the C# code:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String messageOut = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["tester"];
            MessageBox.Show(messageOut);
        }
```

And here's the app.config that I've created as a test

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="buttonText" value="message from ray"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

As you can see, there is no key for "tester" in the app.config and I would've expected an exception. However, what happens is that I just get a blank message box.

Update:

Thanks for the answer, Hawxby.
I guess part 2 for me is to understand try and catch.
Would this work here?

```
   MessageBox.Show(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["text"].ToString());

   try
   {
      String tester = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["text"].ToString();
      tester = null;

   }
   catch
   {
       MessageBox.Show("Missing key!");
   }
```

Comment: Are you using this specific code for a reason, or do you want any example of code that generates an exception?

Comment: I'm using this code because it involves app.config and..well... it's easy enough for me at this point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you request a config item that doesn't exist it returns a null string. If you for example try calling `.ToString()` on your `messageOut` variable that'll cause one because you can't call `ToString()` on a null object.

If you are just wanting your application to throw an exception

```
throw new Exception("Something broke");
```

Comment: Fantastic answer. To the point and easy to understand, plus I learned something new today. :)